# Justify-content issue

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a toolbar and I want to place my span element as center of my flex display of the toolbar. I am missing something.

CSS

```
.toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #1976d2;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
  } n

  .toolbar img {
    margin: 0 16px;
  }

  .toolbar span {
      justify-content: center;
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="toolbar" role="banner">
    <span>Recipe Book</span>
</div>
```

I got a solution like this. But I like to understand about `justify-content : center` for display flex.

HTML

```
  <div class="toolbar" role="banner">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
     <span>Recipe Book</span>
    <div class="spacer"></div>

    </div>
```

CSS :

```
.spacer {
    flex: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `justify-content: center`. Aligning with `align-items` will align based on the cross-axis of your flex-direction. `justify-content: center` will align based on the regular axis of your flexbox.

Set the `flex-direction` to `flex-direction: column` to better understand what I am talking about in action.

On a sidenote, just changing the flex-direction could work too for this specific example.

```css
.toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #1976d2;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
```

```html
<div class="toolbar" role="banner">
    <span>Recipe Book</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

run code.

```css
.toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
    background-color: #1976d2;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
  } n

  .toolbar img {
    margin: 0 16px;
  }

  .toolbar span {
      justify-content: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="toolbar" role="banner">
    <span>Recipe Book</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `justify-content: center` to `toolbar`

Comment: it doesn't work that way

Comment: @NicoletaWilskon Sorry I left out that you should also add display flex on the `toolbar span`